# Fixed Size Array of Structure type

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling, unsafe

how do I declare fixed-size array of a structure type in C# :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1), Serializable]
public unsafe struct MyStruct{
    ...
}

public class MyClass {
    ...
    public fixed MyStruct myStruct[256];
}
```

this will result to CS1663 : fixed size buffers of struct type is not allowed, how do I workaround this ?, I prefer not to use C# or "Managed Collection data structure" type, as I need to frequently marshall this to native C++

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your C# struct uses only primitive data types and has exactly the same layout as your native struct in C++, you can get around these restrictions with manual memory management and unsafe code. As a bonus, you will improve performance by avoiding marshalling.

Allocate the memory:

```
IntPtr arr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (sizeof (MyStruct) * 256);
```

This is basically `malloc`, so the allocated memory is outside the awareness of the GC.

You can pass the IntPtr to native code as if it were a `MyStruct[256]` and only the IntPtr will be marshalled, not the memory it points to. Native and managed code can access the same memory directly.

To read/write the structs in the array with C#, use C# pointers:

```
static unsafe MyStruct GetMyStructAtIndex (IntPtr arr, int index)
{
    MyStruct *ptr = ((MyStruct *)arr) + index;
    return *ptr;
}

static unsafe void SetMyStructAtIndex (IntPtr arr, int index, MyStruct value)
{
    MyStruct *ptr = ((MyStruct *)arr) + index;
    *ptr = value;
}
```

Don't forget to

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal (arr);
```

when you're done with the memory, to `free` it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't; [per the definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx)

> The only restriction is that the array type must be `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `sbyte`, `ushort`, `uint`, `ulong`, `float`, or `double.`

Comment: @uray the only thing I can suggest is a regular array. If that isn't possible, then...