# implement c function and parameter pointer struct to c#?

Tags: c#, pointers, parameters, struct, dllimport

I Have a problem about implementint of C++ DLL to C#

My Header File code is this :

```
typedef struct{    
 uchar  Command[4];     
 ushort Lc;    
 uchar  DataIn[512];    
 ushort Le;    
}CON_SEND;



typedef struct{    
 ushort LenOut;     
 uchar  DataOut[512];    
 uchar  outA;    
 uchar  outB;    
}CON_RESP;

SDK_C_DLL_API int   Csdk_Cmd(uchar port, CON_SEND * ConSend,CON_RESP * ConResp);
SDK_C_DLL_API int   Csdk_Open(uchar port);
```

and my C# class

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CON_SEND
{
    public byte[] Command;
    public System.UInt16 Lc;
    public byte[] DataIn;
    public System.UInt16 Le;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CON_RESP
{
    public System.UInt16 LenOut;
    public byte[] DataOut;
    public byte outA;
    public byte outB;
}


[DllImport("SDK_C.dll")]
public static extern System.Int16 Csdk_Cmd(System.Byte port, ref CON_SEND ConSend, ref CON_RESP ConResp);

[DllImport("SDK_C.dll")]
public static extern System.Int16 Csdk_Open(System.Byte port);
```

now i use Csdk_Cmd; is working no problem this code :

```
if(SDK_C.Csdk_Open(0x00)== 0)
    lblStatus.Text = "Gate 0 is busy";
else
    lblStatus.Text = "You can use Gate 0";
```

but when i try to use this code Csdk_Cmd given "NotSupportedException"

```
CON_SEND SendCon = new CON_SEND(); 
 SendCon.Command = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x72 };
 SendCon.DataIn = new byte[]{0xAA, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xAD, 0xAE, 0xAF, 0xA0};
 SendCon.Lc = 0x0007;
 SendCon.Le = 0x0000;

CON_RESP RespCon = new CON_RESP();
 RespCon.DataOut = new byte[512];

SDK_C.Csdk_Cmd(0, ref SendCon, ref RespCon); // THIS LINE
```

Comment: I have an idea of whats going on, but just to double check can you post the full error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a guess really, but you are declaring your structs with inline (fixed) arrays in C++, so you'll need to tell c# to to do that too. You can do this with [Fixed Size Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CON_SEND
{
   public fixed byte Command[4];
   public System.UInt16 Lc;
   public fixed byte DataIn[512];
   public System.UInt16 Le;
}
```

Warning: this code needs to be compiled with unsafe and appear in unsafe block.

Alternatively, you could look into better defining the marshaling attributes for your struct:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66244/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-2-Marshaling-Simple-Type

(See @DavidHeffernan, answer below)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, [depends on your performance requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973998/fixed-size-array-of-structure-type). The unsafe struct can be "marshaled" faster by just exposing the memory pointer, but I agree its less readable/usable.

Comment: but i cant add data to fixed byte array.  

CON_SEND cnSend = new CON_SEND();


int len=4;//just guessing at this

byte[] safe = new byte[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    safe[i] = cnSend.Command[i];

fixed (byte* converted = safe)
{
    // This will update the safe and converted arrays.
    //0xE0, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x72
    converted[0] = 0xE0;
    converted[1] = 0xA0;
    converted[2] = 0xC4;
    converted[3] = 0x72;
}

Comment: @Recep Yes, fixed arrays are awkward. Why do you feel the need to use them? If you avoided them you could indeed use `SendCon.Command = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x72 };`

Comment: @RecepAkkoç What are your performance metrics? David's answer (below) will be more readable/usable in C# code, but does an implicit double copy (Marshal in, marshal out). While both methods are correct, you need to chose the one that best fits your program.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Thanks for your comment and the update to the answer

Comment: `public fixed byte Command[4];` is given error. Its need unsafe.
I set to `unsafe public unsafe fixed byte Command[4];`

And I try to set with 'SendCon.Command = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x72 }'

Given this errors : 
'Error 1 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer C:\Projects\test\DeviceApplication1\DeviceApplication1\Run.cs 90 21'
AND
'Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'byte*' C:\Projects\test\DeviceApplication1\DeviceApplication1\Run.cs 90 49'

Comment: Thans @DavidHeffernan but `public fixed byte Command[4];` is given error. Its need unsafe.
I set to `unsafe public unsafe fixed byte Command[4];`

And I try to set with 'SendCon.Command = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x72 }'

Given this errors : 

`Error 1 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer C:\Projects\test\DeviceApplication1\DeviceApplication1\Run.cs 90 21`

AND

`Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'byte*' C:\Projects\test\DeviceApplication1\DeviceApplication1\Run.cs 90 49`

Comment: @RecepAkkoç Yes, that is precisely my point. Look at the code in my answer. Since it doesn't use fixed, you don't need unsafe. And you can use the assignment `SendCon.Command = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x72 };` That may be more convenient to you. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Your struct declarations are not correct. The C code has inline byte arrays and simply put, they do not match the default marshalling for `byte[]`. The easiest way to fix it is to use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)`. Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct CON_SEND
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] Command;
    public ushort Lc;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
    public byte[] DataIn;
    public ushort Le;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct CON_RESP
{
    public ushort LenOut;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
    public byte[] DataOut;
    public byte outA;
    public byte outB;
}
```

Your functions also have incorrect return value. A C `int` maps to C# `int`. So they declarations should be:

```
[DllImport("SDK_C.dll")]
public static extern int Csdk_Cmd(byte port, ref CON_SEND ConSend, 
    ref CON_RESP ConResp);

[DllImport("SDK_C.dll")]
public static extern int Csdk_Open(byte port);
```

The other thing to double check is the calling convention. The C# function above use the default of `Stdcall`. Are you sure that the C code also does? Since there is nothing specified between the return value and the function name, I suspect that the functions are actually `Cdecl`. In which case you need:

```
[DllImport("SDK_C.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Csdk_Cmd(byte port, ref CON_SEND ConSend, 
    ref CON_RESP ConResp);

[DllImport("SDK_C.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Csdk_Open(byte port);
```

Comment: `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` AND `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` givven error when compile. if I delete it dont give error but DataOut is filling zero. No have data :(

Comment: The code compiles just fine for me. If you won't tell me what the compiler error is I cannot guess.